# How to use flexbox inside a fixed container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I have a div that is `position: fixed;` within the viewport. Within this are a series of child elements that use `display: flex;` and I need a scrollable element to fill 100% of the height of the flexed element. The problem I am having is that because done of the parent elements of the scrollable element have a fixed height, so the scrollable element just pushed the bottom of the flexed element rather than scroll.

Please see the following JSBin example. In this example, the blue block needs to extend to 100% the height of the red block, with the contents of the blue block still being scrollable. Needs to work in IE10+, latest Firefox and Chrome:

https://jsbin.com/terimim/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Something like this? https://jsbin.com/jefuzidojo/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Almost - it doesn't seem to work in Firefox.

Comment: Okay. Addressed that issue and posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two primary issues causing the layout problem. They are each explained here:

- [Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)
- [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276)

[revised demo](https://jsbin.com/xafunimosu/1/edit?html,css,output)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

#menu {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 12;
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
}

#menu-contents {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

#menu-pane-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #eeffcc;
}

#menu-panes {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.menu-pane {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.menu-pane-overflow {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.menu-item {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div id="menu-contents">
    <div id="menu-header">HEADER</div>
    <div id="menu-pane-wrapper">
      <div id="menu-panes">
        <div class="menu-pane">
          <div class="menu-pane-overflow">
            <div class="menu-pane-scroll">
              <div class="menu-item">1</div>
              <div class="menu-item">2</div>
              <div class="menu-item">3</div>
              <div class="menu-item">4</div>
              <div class="menu-item">5</div>
              <div class="menu-item">6</div>
              <div class="menu-item">7</div>
              <div class="menu-item">8</div>
              <div class="menu-item">9</div>
              <div class="menu-item">10</div>
              <div class="menu-item">11</div>
              <div class="menu-item">12</div>
              <div class="menu-item">13</div>
              <div class="menu-item">14</div>
              <div class="menu-item">15</div>
              <div class="menu-item">16</div>
              <div class="menu-item">17</div>
              <div class="menu-item">18</div>
              <div class="menu-item">19</div>
              <div class="menu-item">20</div>
              <div class="menu-item">21</div>
              <div class="menu-item">22</div>
              <div class="menu-item">23</div>
              <div class="menu-item">24</div>
              <div class="menu-item">25</div>
              <div class="menu-item">26</div>
              <div class="menu-item">27</div>
              <div class="menu-item">28</div>
              <div class="menu-item">29</div>
              <div class="menu-item">30</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```